# Destructor is called while there is still a reference

Tags: c++

From earlier great posts (such as [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)), I learned that a reference can prolong the life of a temporary object. So, I decided to try this myself and obtained a very unexpected (to me) result. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B {
public:
  B() {cout << "Constructor of B" << endl;}
  ~B() {cout << "Destructor of B" << endl;}
  void methodB(){cout << "B is alive!" << endl;}
};

class A {
public: 
  A() {cout << "Constructor of A" << endl;}
  ~A() {cout << "Destructor of A" << endl;}
  B &methodA() {
    cout << "Entering methodA()" << endl;
    B b;
    B &a = b;
    cout << "Exiting methodA()" << endl;
    return a;
  }
};

int main() {
  A a;
  B &b = a.methodA();
  cout << "After the call to methodA()" << endl;
  b.methodB();
  return 0;
}
```

I would expect that the object of class B be destroyed when main() completes. However, this is the output that I got:

```
Constructor of A
Entering methodA()
Constructor of B
Exiting methodA()
Destructor of B
After the call to methodA()
B is alive!
Destructor of A
```

Note how the call to methodB() is performed after the destructor of B had been executed. What is the explanation for this behavior?

Comment: You have distinct instances of `A`'s and `B`'s in your sample. They are unrelated!

Comment: in methodA(), you return a reference to a local variable. Your compiler should warn you about it, don't do that.

Comment: You are returning a reference to a variable on the stack. The B you initialize in methodA is destructed at the end of the method. You then return a reference to it which now points to garbage data.

Comment: the "Destructor of B" you are seeing is the local B created in methodB() being destroyed, this is expected.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. As the output witnesses, the constructor of A is called only once, same goes for constructor of B. Doesn't this mean that I have only one instance of each class?

Comment: This is the standard behavior. Return a copy of your object if you want to keep it. If your concerned with performances, this is ofter a free copy because of "copy elision optimization".

Comment: That is the point I started with: I understood that one can reference a temporary object and the object will be alive as long as the reference is. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This is not a temporary object, you return a reference to a normal named variable. The fact that object is destroyed before the reference to it goes out of scope doesn't make this object temporary.

Answer (score 1):

> I learned that a reference can prolong the life of a temporary object

There are no references to temporary objects in your code. You return a reference to a local variable that is destroyed after you return from `A::methodA()`. "B is alive!" is printed just because you don't reference any `B`'s member variables in `B::methodB()`. This is invalid, but it may (or may not) work.

Calling `b.methodB()` is basically calling a function that has implicit hidden first argument of type `B* const` and value `&b`. In your case `b` object is already destroyed (you saw the destructor executed), `&b` points to some memory on the stack where the object was placed when it was alive, but because you don't reference any `B`'s members this pointer is never dereferenced and this works (though you should never rely on this).

Comment: Isn't local variable a kind of temporary object? (in fact, a local variable has a larger scope: a temporary object's scope is only the expression where it appears). What is the principal difference between them? (i.e. why can't the destruction of a local variable be postponed in the same way as the destruction of a temporary object is postponed when there is a reference?)

Comment: No, local variables and temporaries are different things. Paragraph 12.2 [class.temporary] of C++ standard describes what temporaries are.